# Cannot startproject when installing oTree on Windows 10 ('otree' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module)

Tags: python, windows, otree

I'm trying to reinstall oTree on my Windows 10 computer after some difficulties. I uninstalled oTree and Python, and reinstalled Python and am trying to reinstall oTree, both with the latest available versions (Python 3.6.4, oTree 2.0.18). The problem comes after I do the Python install and the oTree install, when I run from the appropriate directory (`C:\Users\Sarah`) the command `otree startproject otree`. It refuses to run as follows:

```
C:\Users\Sarah>otree startproject otree
Include sample games? (y or n): y
CommandError: 'otree' conflicts with the name of an existing Python module and cannot be used as a project name. Please try another name.
```

There is, however, no otree folder within C:\Users\Sarah

I have installed it from this location in the past with recent versions of oTree before the latest update (like two weeks ago), and got everything working fine. I have tried many things, usually many times over, to get this to work but keep returning to the same error. Things I've tried:

- with and without sample games
- uninstalled oTree again, and tried reinstalling it again
- uninstalled oTree again, then uninstalled Python again, then reinstalled Python, then reinstalled oTree
- same but with reboots at each step
- same but after uninstalling Python deleted Python and pip folders within the AppData folder on my computer (ensuring that when I did that, there was nothing remaining on my computer with oTree in the name except shortcuts in the computer's Recent links and some Word docs where I discuss it)

In case it helps, here is version info:

```
C:\Users\Sarah>otree --version
oTree: 2.0.18 - Django: 1.11.2

C:\Users\Sarah>pip3 -V
pip 9.0.1 from c:\users\sarah\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions anyone has.

Best regards,

-Sarah

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that it is case-sensitive, and "otree" is a reserved word, so one must do "otree startproject oTree".